# Blur image on image to byte array conversion

Tags: android, image, camera, blur

I want to show multiple images in `GridView` captured from camera.
Problem is that i am converting camera captures image to byte array.
and after conversion image turns to blur.
And on `GridView` item click i want to show that full size image.

(As I want to show `GridView` of images with some text at top and bottom of `GridView` I have to use `ScrollView` and for that I have used custom `GridView` as there is scroll problem.)

Here is my code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFolder/";+imgcurTime+"_"+i+".jpg";
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(_path);
                    // File.createTempFile(filename, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, out);
                    thePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    out.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
```